# What is the proper way to access a function inside a different controller

Tags: angularjs

What is the proper way to access a function side controller A from inside controller B?

The best method I've been able to find is to push the functions to a shared service, so I've started to move all of my functions and logic inside this service, which feels like the wrong way to do things.

My scenario is that I have a view utilizing two different controllers. Each one has its own set of tabs for navigation. I need to be able to navigate between views and to specific tabs inside.

Is a service really the best way to do this? Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to communicate between two controllers is by using the service. You have common method defined inside the service and then inject that service wherever you need that function to use.

Use $broadcast service to trigger the event and all.

Following is the plnkr which shows how to communicate between the controllers.

`Plnkr :`http://plnkr.co/edit/d98mOuVvFMr1YtgRr9hq?p=preview